# Tikz-uml error when using positioning keywords

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I use the `tikz-uml` package with MikTeX. I put it in the '...latex/misc' directory and used the 'Refresh FNDB' function in the settings.

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Tikz Stuff
\usepackage{tikz}
%Required for Tikz-UML
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlsimpleclass{A}
\umlemptyclass[below left=2cm and 2cm of A, anchor=north]{B}
\umlclass[right=4cm of B.north, anchor=north]{C}{i : int \\ r : double}{}
\umlVHVinherit[arm2=-1.2cm]{B}{A}
\umlVHVinherit[arm2=-1.2cm]{C}{A}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The package itself works. But, if I use the positioning keywords like above or below left I get the following error:

> pdflatex> !TIKZUML ERROR : in umlclass, invalid option below left

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you try `left below`?

Comment: `/tikz/nodes={below left=2cm and 2cm of A, anchor=north}` does work. Though, judging from the source, this will probably not help always. There is some weird PGFkeys stuff going on, internally.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need to `\usepackage` the packages that `tikz-uml` need, it loads them on its own.

Comment: I tried `\umlemptyclass[left below of A, anchor=north]{B}` in this minimal example but i geht the same error anyway

Comment: I resolved the Problem for me with using another Package called pgf-umlcd http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlcd/

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, the relative positioning feature is only documented online, I assume it is not included in the official release 1.0b from February 2013.

Try the snapshot from March 2013:

> [TikZ-UML startpage](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/src/tikzuml-HEAD-2013-03-19.tbz)
>
> The latest snapshot was released on 19 Mar 2013
>
> [http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/src/tikzuml-HEAD-2013-03-19.tbz](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/src/tikzuml-HEAD-2013-03-19.tbz)

And you have to add the TikZ `positioning` package in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

Comment: Tried this today, it doesn't work with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Comment: unfortunetaly, I cannot find a working example anymore, and also get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\usetikzibrary{positioning}` before or after `\usepackage{tikz-uml}` works fine with the new release of tikz-uml available soon.